# Match any list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to pattern match any list without iterating through the two cases: empty or non-empty list ?

I would like to fix the following code:

```
foo [] = "something else"
foo [_:_] = "something else"
```

Since the part in `something else`  is the same I would like to remove it from one place.

Thank you.

Comment: The first line `foo x = something` matches any list.  What specifically are you looking to do?

Comment: http://learnyouahaskell.com

Comment: Are you trying to match for example Integers in your first line and lists in the other lines? That's not possible - what would be the type of the function foo?

Comment: Note that your 3rd equation describes a list with a single elemnt, which is another list. You probably meant (x:xs) instead. As long as you have this, the type checker will infer some type [[a]], when you expect something like [a]

Answer (score 8):

The pattern `_` matches anything without binding it to a name. A name, like say, `xs` also matches anything. So you can do either:

`foo _ = "something else"`
or
`foo xs = "something else"`

If "something else" truly does not depend on the value of `xs` the first form is preferred, so that another programmer (and you) can quickly spot that the value is irrelevant in this particular equation.

Unfortunately, your first case is already of the second form, so it matches **all** possibilities. The other cases will never be reached.

Comment: I've removed the 'catch all' part. Sorry

Comment: Also, with `-Wall`, GHC will warn about the usused variable `xs` if you mention it in the pattern head. The underscore is not a variable and therefore won't issue this warning.

Comment: And if for some reason you want to give the ignored parameter a name, `foo _xs = "something else"` - beginning the name with an underscore will prevent the unused variable warning.